# "Reverse" of a rotation matrix for superposition $\colon A$ on $B \to B$ on $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a (right-multiplying) 3D rotation matrix which best superposes one set of coordinates $A$ onto the system of another one $B$.

Is there an operation that can be performed to obtain the rotation matrix that would superpose $B$ onto $A$ instead?

Intuitively, it would seem that the information for this still ought to be in the original matrix, but not being a mathematician, I don't know how to do this. If this is somehow not possible, could anyone explain why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you simply want to "reverse" of your rotation (which I will call $R$).  That is, you'd like to take the inverse of your linear transformation.  As you say, "the information is all there", so your transformation will be invertible.

So, rather than using $R$, use [$R^{-1}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix).

In fact, because $R$ is a rotation, it is an [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) transformation, which means we will simply have $R^{-1} = R^T$, where $R^T$ is the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of $R$.

Comment: Thank you, that was very clear. I suspected the inverse would be involved, but not quite as straightforwardly and I'm surprised it actually boils down to something as simple as the transpose, ultimately.

Comment: Glad to help.  This is pretty much the reason that orthogonal transformations (i.e. any combination of rotations and reflections) are extremely nice.  If you ever look into linear algebra and/or matrix analysis, there are a whole slew of theorems describing other matrices in terms of orthogonal matrices.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse matrix will send you back.  So you'll be wanting to look up ways to find the inverse of a $3\times3$ matrix.